# What is the most efficient way to cluster clusters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have used kmeans to cluster my data. Now I want to cluster the clusters so that the clustered clusters consist of the individual clusters from the first round of clustering.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# create dataframe
n1 = 336
n2 = 200
x_list = np.array(range(0, n1))
y_list = np.array(range(0, n2))
x_list = np.repeat([x_list], n2, axis=0).flatten() # width
y_list = np.repeat(y_list, n1, axis=0).flatten() # height
# normalize x, y to avoid skewing the clustering
norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x_list)
norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y_list)
normal_array_x = np.round(x_list / norm_x, 6)
normal_array_y = np.round(y_list / norm_y, 6)
data = {'x_position_norm': normal_array_x,
        'y_position_norm': normal_array_y}
features = pd.DataFrame(data).to_numpy()

kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=16800, n_init=3, max_iter=3, random_state=1)
kmeans.fit(features)

kmeans2 = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=4200, n_init=3, max_iter=3, random_state=1)
kmeans2.fit(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

At the moment, I am clustering the cluster centers. Is there a better/ more efficient way to cluster that guarantees clusters in the second round of clustering are consisting of clusters from the first round of clusters?

Comment: Define 'better/ more efficient'. What is wrong with km?

Comment: It is very slow for my application. I have to cluster 120.000 different datasets where each dataset contains 67200 datapoints and must have 16800 cluster centers initially. I was wondering whether there is a faster clustering algorithm than kmeans.

Comment: I had a look into mini batch kmeans which performs slightly faster but I was hoping to find a clustering algorithm designed for big data that potentially relies on sparse computations.

Comment: I assume that the first round of clustering causes more trouble than the second. Shouldn't you try to improve the first round before you even start discussing the second? In other words, are you asking the right question?

Answer (score 0):

Each clustering method has its own characteristics. It only depends on what your data looks like.

For Bottom-up clustering, `spectral clustering` will work well.

[Plot a cluster map](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/structured_heatmap.html)

[image: cluster map]

Here is a list of clustering methods.

> [Overview of clustering methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods)
> [image]

Comment: I have too many clusters for spectral clustering. It works well for a low number of clusters but I have 16800 clusters initially.

Comment: @former_Epsilon you don't need to run spectral cluster twice, it has an `affinity_matrix`. I put a cluster map to help you understand this.